# Integration of a complicated rational function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to derive the integration as is showed below:

$\int_0^{\gamma} \frac{\lambda_1^2 \lambda_2 \lambda_3 \text{a}^4 \text{w1} \left(1-\text{b}^2 (\gamma -y)\right) \left(1-\text{c}^2 (\gamma -y)\right)^2}{\left(\lambda_2 \text{a} \left(1-\text{b}^2 (\gamma -y)\right)+\text{w2} (\gamma -y)\right) \left(\lambda_1 \lambda_3 \text{a}^2 \left(1-\text{b}^2 y\right) \left(1-\text{c}^2 (\gamma -y)\right)+\lambda_3 \text{a} \text{w1} \left(1-\text{b}^2 y\right) (\gamma -y)+\lambda_1 \text{a} \text{w1} y \left(1-\text{c}^2 (\gamma -y)\right)\right)^2}dy$

It is complicated if the traditional method is applied. Is there any solution to obtain the result more simple? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can append a subscript to a variable in latex using underscores, i.e., \lambda_3 gives $\lambda_3$. Given the nasticity of your integral, I highly recommend you make use of them.

Comment: Thank you. The equation has been updated.

Comment: I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have transcribed it correctly, Maple actually claims to obtain a closed-form antiderivative.  However, it is too big to display (and certainly too big to copy here).  Note, by the way, that in many cases the denominator will have roots in the interval $[0,\gamma]$ and the definite integral will not exist.

Do you have any particular values in mind for the parameters?

Comment: Mathematica has also returned an exact form, however it is too big as well. Therefore, I am thinking of another method to obtain the result instead of direct calculation?

Comment: You're integrating a rational function of $y$, with a denominator that has quadratic and linear factors.  In terms of the roots of those factors, it should be not too bad.